# Getting insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment while running Jboss at Docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile, digital-ocean

We are getting below issue while running the Jboss at Runtime inside Docker.

We have created a .sh file to execute Jboss.

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00007f67a05ef000, 65536, 1) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 65536 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /usr/local/ABC/hs_err_pid42.log
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.
Rama.

Comment: Hello @Rama, what are the other information in the logfile /usr/local/ABC/hs_err_pid42.log? What else did you do to solve your problem?

Comment: Can you share your `docker run` line or compose.yml config's for how you are starting your JBoss container?

Comment: Please, take a look at this article it can help you out:
https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2017/03/14/java-inside-docker